# How can one <img> tag be used to execute 2 different js functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

How can I set up one image, that when clicked changes to another image and then when clicked again reverts back to the original image while still carrying out functions independently. In my example I want a Play button that when pressed turns to a pause button. 
However I need to have both play and pause functionalities when the correct button is pressed. These work on do different buttons but I would like the one button to have all the functionality. I have tried a few things but everytime, one of the play/pause functions are not letting the other work.

```
  $('#startSlider').click(function (){
    if (document.getElementById("startSlider").src = "Play.png"){
     document.getElementById("startSlider").src = "Pause.png";
     scrollSlider();
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("startSlider").src != "Play.png"){
     clearTimeout(tmOt);
     document.getElementById("startSlider").src = "Play.png";
    }
  });
```

---

```
<img src="Play.png" id="startSlider"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like using classes in these situations as it makes the code a little easier to follow:

```
$('#startSlider').click(function (){
   $(this).toggleClass('pause')

   if ( $(this).hasClass('pause') ) {
      // Button is paused change to play
      $(this).attr('src', 'Play.png')

      // Pause function goes here

   } else {
      // Button is play change to pause
      $(this).attr('src', 'Pause.png')

      //play function goes here

   }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

**problem is in your `if` block,
you are using `=` not `==`**

```
if (document.getElementById("startSlider").src = "Play.png"){// you are assigning here not comparing
```

you are assigning `play.png` every times when the click calls on the image.

---

you are using jquery then why are you not using [this](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/) to make it more simple.

```
$('#startSlider').click(function (){
   if (this.src == "play.png"){
       this.src = "pause.png";
    }else{
    this.src = "play.png";
    } 
});
```

[check this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/v404aypn/)

Comment: Govind, please indent your code correctly, it would make me so happy:)

Comment: @myfunkyside i am trying to make you happy ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a little state machine. You keep the states inside an object, and handle the next state in the event listener of the button:

```
var states = {
  _next: 'play',
  next: function() {
    return this[this._next]()
  },
  play: function() {
    img.src = 'pause.jpg'
    button.textContent = 'Pause'
    this._next = 'pause'
  },
  pause: function() {
    img.src = 'play.jpg'
    button.textContent = 'Play'
    this._next = 'play'
  }
}

button.addEventListener('click', states.next.bind(states))
```

This is more of a general answer to your problem, that you'd have to adapt to your code.

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/moxoca/1/edit *

* The images might take a second to load.